# Using NamedCredentials to getSessionId

Tags: apex, metadata-api, namedcredentials

Im trying to deploy components from one salesforce org to another salesforce org in LightningComponent using named credentials and connected apps to establish the connection.But I am unable to retrieve the access token from named credentials, which is required for retrieving metadata using the ApexWrapper MetadataAPI.

This is the method I am using:

```
HttpRequest Request = new HttpRequest();
string Consumerkey = 'XXXXXXX';
string callbackUrl ='XXXXXXX';
Request.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredential/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id='+Consumerkey+'&redirect_uri='+callbackUrl+'&state=mystate');
Request.setMethod('POST');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse Response = http.send(Request);
System.debug(Response.getBody());

    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(String Accesstoken)
    {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = Accesstoken;
        return service;
    }
```

Comment: Can you not just get the session id from `UserInfo.getSessionId();`?

Comment: Is this using apex code, or is this an external program?

Comment: @battery.cord Using Apexcode only.

Comment: @JohnTowers . im trying to deploy components from one salesforce org to another salesforce org in LightningComponent and im using named credentials and connected apps to establish the connection. UserInfo.getSessionId() will provide sessionID of current or Source org only. I need sessionID of the targetOrg for deployment.

Comment: Got it. Can you add that to your question so it's clear that you're trying to access the metadata of a different org? You should also show the code where you're performing the callout since that's likely where the problem is.